# The privilege to speak in dialect at university and internationally

Tags: dialects, academia, non-native-english, received-pronunciation, insular-english

Anecdote. A friend of mine works at the Chemistry department of a university in the Netherlands. My friend went to a scientific conference in continental Europe. The participants from continental Europe (the Netherlands, Germany, France, Spain, Scandinavia...) all communicated in simple but clear BBC English. The British participants spoke with a strong accent (dialect). As a result, everybody unterstood each other, but nobody understood the British.

Question. Do British scientists have the privilege to speak at their university in a dialect that deviates strongly from BBC English? And when they go to an international meeting, does the same privilege apply, meaning that they have no obligation to adjust their language so that foreigners can actually understand what they say?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it asks (i) for judgement on what the OP sees as a “privilege” but no privilege has been established. (ii) Its second part is flawed as ignores the obvious, i.e. the British scientist must have passed through his career and education with that accent, and finally (iii) that all languages have commonly used accents.

Comment: I've known a lot of non native English speaking academics and few spoke with a perfect RP accent (although often those with strong accents were still understandable). Also, you should listen to the accents the BBC lets on these days. There might be a question you could ask on Academia SE but currently this reads like a rant.

Comment: Were the British scientists ("participants")  from different parts of the country or from one region/country? You said they spoke with a *thick* accent, so that would mean they came from the same area. If they were from Scotland, Northern Ireland, or the [West Midlands](https://youtu.be/R6_8OEvi85E?si=Cdi1JRYp57N6YVY8&t=190) take comfort in knowing there are British native speakers who sometimes find their accents tricky to understand.

Comment: Hasn't there been in England for decades now a concerted democratizing movement away from RP, so that people feel it's their prerogative to speak in their regional accents?  In the US, people who go to school to get degrees in broadcast journalism long have been taught to lose their regional accents and speak in a strange broadcast-journalistese.

Comment: Scientists believe in accurate research, interpretation, recommendations, dissemination of knowledge .... They **must** subscribe to Gricean maxims. One of these is 'communicate clearly' (which surely any person would wish to do anyway). If one's idiolect / accent regularly leads to confusion, one needs to get  an interpreter and/or standardise more. // But who decides when 'regularly' is the case?

Comment: Somewhat related but in no particular order: [1](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/139434), [2](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/129624), [3](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/16858), [4](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/13446), [5](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/176921), [6](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/194203), [7](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/120004), [8](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/165893), [9](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/145912), [10](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/110105), [11](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/85286).

Comment: All the non-native English speakers "communicated in clear BBC English". What? If they could speak it (which I doubt very highly), they could understand it, so what you claim is just not true. Here's your mistake: The BBC presenters speak British English, so your participants couldn't have used BBC English  without already understanding it.

Comment: Several of the commenters above have treated that as a problem specific to the academia, and have therefore referred the OP to the Academia Stack Exchange, but the problem is really a matter of general politeness: when communicating with non-native speakers (particularly those who do not use the language every day), politeness requires that, as far as one can, one avoid the pronunciation, vocabulary, idioms, etc., that are not normally taught to the learners of that language. That applies to any language, not just English.

Comment: @jsw29 How would native speakers know what non-natives are taught to understand, or how to imitate a dialect and accent not their own? Who aside from professional voice actors are taught how to do that? I'm sure I myself couldn't manage to convincingly imitate Received Pronunciation, or Scots English, or West Country English, or Northern English, or Irish English, or West Virginia English, or California English, or Texas English, or New Zealand English, or South Africa English, etc.

Comment: @tchrist, true, it would be hard for native speakers (other than those who teach English to foreigners) to do that perfectly, but it is surely not too much to expect them to try, rather than be oblivious to the problem, and it is the obliviousness that the OP is objecting to.